# Calculate difference in counts from two tables

Tags: google-bigquery

I am basically trying to calculate the difference in counts from two tables. My query would look something like

```
 SELECT count(user_id) FROM [enter] - SELECT count(user_id) FROM [exit];
```

'enter' and 'exit' are two separate tables. Basically i am looking for a single query which can give me the difference. Want to avoid using two separate queries and calculate the difference in the application.

While executing the above query i get the following error.

Error: Encountered " "-" "- "" at line 1, column 36. Was expecting: EOF

Comment: What's the problem doing this?

Comment: I get error -> Error: Encountered " "-" "- "" at line 1, column 36. Was expecting: <EOF>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this would work for you

```
select d1.count,d2.count,d1.count-d2.count as diff from
(
SELECT 1 as id,count(1) as count FROM [publicdata:samples.github_timeline]
) d1
join (
SELECT 1 as id,count(1) as count FROM [publicdata:samples.github_nested]
) d2 
on d1.id=d2.id
```

Comment: Perfect!! Solves the problem for me. So basically you are creating a helper table with id column and joining, nice hack.

Comment: FYI, you can simplify this query with a CROSS JOIN: "SELECT d1.count - d2.count FROM (SELECT COUNT(1) AS count FROM [...timeline]) d1 CROSS JOIN (SELECT COUNT(1) AS count FROM [...nested]) d2". But be careful with CROSS JOINs in general, because they can generate way too much data when used on tables that are too large.